# Executable problems

Tags: python, pygame, exe, py2exe, sys

I made a script in python 2.6. When I tried running it on the computer(Windows Vista Home Basic) it worked perfectly fine but when I tried making it in an .exe the problems started. The problems were that when I clicked on the executable on other computers(windows 7 and I think the new version of windows vista) it came up with an error box and disappears really quickly. It disappears so quickly that I can't read all of the error messages. But I saw part of the message saying that there was an error on line 70 and line 54 and that there is an 'importError: DLL load failed; The specified module could not be found'. For some reason it looks perfectly fine to me. In case I made the script into an executable with py2exe(latest one). The lines are highlighted in the script below.

```
import pygame, random, sys
from pygame.locals import *

WINDOWWIDTH = 600
WINDOWHEIGHT = 600
RED = (255, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
TEXTCOLOR = WHITE
BACKGROUNDCOLOR = BLACK
FPS = 40
ASTEROIDMINSIZE = 10
ASTEROIDMAXSIZE = 40
ASTEROIDMINSPEED = 1
ASTEROIDMAXSPEED = 8
ADDNEWASTEROIDRATE = 6
PLAYERMOVERATE = 5
MAXHEALTH = 3

def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

def waitForPlayerToPressKey():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE: # pressing escape quits
                    terminate()
                return

def playerHasHitBaddie(playerRect, asteroids):
    for a in asteroids:
        if playerRect.colliderect(a['rect']):
            return True
    return False

def drawText(text, font, surface, x, y):
    textobj = font.render(text, 1, TEXTCOLOR)
    textrect = textobj.get_rect()
    textrect.topleft = (x, y)
    surface.blit(textobj, textrect)

# set up pygame, the window, and the mouse cursor
pygame.init()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Dodger')
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

# set up fonts
(LINE 54)font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)

# set up sounds
gameOverSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('gameover.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.load('background.mid')

# set up images
playerImage = pygame.image.load('player.png')
playerRect = playerImage.get_rect()
baddieImage = pygame.image.load('asteroid.png')
tokenImage = pygame.image.load('tokens.png')

# show the "Start" screen
drawText('Asteroid Shower', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3), (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3))
drawText('Press a key to start.', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 30, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 50)
drawText('By Sandy Goetjens', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 100, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 100)
(LINE 70)pygame.display.update()
waitForPlayerToPressKey()

topScore = 0
while True:
    # set up the start of the game
    asteroids = []
    score = 0
    playerRect.topleft = (WINDOWWIDTH / 2, WINDOWHEIGHT - 50)
    moveLeft = moveRight = moveUp = moveDown = False
    reverseCheat = slowCheat = False
    asteroidAddCounter = 0
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)

    while True: # the game loop runs while the game part is playing
        score += 1 # increase score

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()

            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == ord('z'):
                    reverseCheat = True
                if event.key == ord('x'):
                    slowCheat = True
                if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                    moveRight = False
                    moveLeft = True
                if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                    moveLeft = False
                    moveRight = True
                if event.key == K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                    moveDown = False
                    moveUp = True
                if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                    moveUp = False
                    moveDown = True

            if event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == ord('z'):
                    reverseCheat = False
                    score = 0
                if event.key == ord('x'):
                    slowCheat = False
                    score = 0
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                        terminate()

                if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                    moveLeft = False
                if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                    moveRight = False
                if event.key == K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                    moveUp = False
                if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                    moveDown = False

            if event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
                # If the mouse moves, move the player where the cursor is.
                playerRect.move_ip(event.pos[0] - playerRect.centerx, event.pos[1] - playerRect.centery)

        # Add new baddies at the top of the screen, if needed.
        if not reverseCheat and not slowCheat:
            asteroidAddCounter += 1
        if asteroidAddCounter == ADDNEWASTEROIDRATE:
            asteroidAddCounter = 0
            asteroidSize = random.randint(ASTEROIDMINSIZE, ASTEROIDMAXSIZE)
            newAsteroid = {'rect': pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOWWIDTH-asteroidSize), 0 - asteroidSize, asteroidSize, asteroidSize),
                        'speed': random.randint(ASTEROIDMINSPEED, ASTEROIDMAXSPEED),
                        'surface':pygame.transform.scale(baddieImage, (asteroidSize, asteroidSize)),
                        }

            asteroids.append(newAsteroid)

        # Move the player around.
        if moveLeft and playerRect.left > 0:
            playerRect.move_ip(-1 * PLAYERMOVERATE, 0)
        if moveRight and playerRect.right < WINDOWWIDTH:
            playerRect.move_ip(PLAYERMOVERATE, 0)
        if moveUp and playerRect.top > 0:
            playerRect.move_ip(0, -1 * PLAYERMOVERATE)
        if moveDown and playerRect.bottom < WINDOWHEIGHT:
            playerRect.move_ip(0, PLAYERMOVERATE)

        # Move the mouse cursor to match the player.
        pygame.mouse.set_pos(playerRect.centerx, playerRect.centery)

        # Move the baddies down.
        for a in asteroids:
            if not reverseCheat and not slowCheat:
                a['rect'].move_ip(0, a['speed'])
            elif reverseCheat:
                a['rect'].move_ip(0, -5)
            elif slowCheat:
                a['rect'].move_ip(0, 1)

         # Delete baddies that have fallen past the bottom.
        for a in asteroids[:]:
            if a['rect'].top > WINDOWHEIGHT:
                asteroids.remove(a)

        # Draw the game world on the window.
        windowSurface.fill(BACKGROUNDCOLOR)

        # Draw the score and top score.
        drawText('Score: %s' % (score), font, windowSurface, 10, 0)
        drawText('Top Score: %s' % (topScore), font, windowSurface, 10, 40)

        # Draw the player's rectangle
        windowSurface.blit(playerImage, playerRect)

        # Draw each baddie
        for a in asteroids:
            windowSurface.blit(a['surface'], a['rect'])

        pygame.display.update()

        # Check if any of the baddies have hit the player.
        if playerHasHitBaddie(playerRect, asteroids):
            if score > topScore:
                topScore = score # set new top score
            break

        mainClock.tick(FPS)

    # Stop the game and show the "Game Over" screen.
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    gameOverSound.play()

    drawText('GAME OVER', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3), (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3))
    drawText('Press a key to play again.', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 80, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 50)
    pygame.display.update()
    waitForPlayerToPressKey()

    gameOverSound.stop()
```

Comment: use the command line to execute the script and post the error. Windows-key+r -> type cmd, enter. use the `cd` command to get to the folder and there type the executable name.

Comment: sorry, but what do you mean, use the command line. Do you mean use the python shell?I've tried running it from the idle shell but it won't start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the full Error you can do this in your program:

```
try:

    something_with_error

except:
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc()
    input()
```

Then you can see the full error.